# What's the best way to store an n^2 network/graph in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, graph, database

I have a network of nodes where every node has information about every other node. What's the most efficient way to store this data? The networks can have sizes up to tens of thousands of nodes.

Should I create a document for each node containing references to each other node, or should I create one massive tree structure which holds all the data? Or is there something else?

Comment: Have you considered a document for each edge?

Comment: Yes, that's the solution where I create a document for each node (edge) which contains values for all other nodes. That's fine, but I'm wondering if there's something better without moving to a graph database.

Comment: Not really. You cannot put all the other nodes in a document, you'll hit the document size limit. A document-per-Edge approach would have a very small document with references to just two nodes and any data on that edge.

Comment: No @Ian Mercer, each edge would have information about each other edge, because they all have information about eachother. That's why I'm not happy with this solution. Having only information about neighbors does not work for my use case.

Comment: I think you need to explain your use cases before anyone can answer this question. There are map-reduce techniques that can be applied to compute graph traversals which might apply. But regardless, you cannot store n of anything in a single document for any significant n so whether it's nodes or edges you'll need an approach that has a document per-node and a document per edge plus any denormalization that might help compute graph traversals. Whether a graph database is better will depend on how large the nodes are, how large the edges are, how they are indexed and your query patterns.